# Hyperref TextFields dont't work when in tabular environment with xetex?

Tags: tables, xetex, hyperref, forms

I created a pdf fillable form in LaTeX using hyperref text fields, then decided that I wanted to change the font of the whole form, so I tried to use `XeTeX` with `fontspec`. Unfortunately, when I do this, some of the TextFields no longer work.

For example, when compiling with `XeTeX`:

```
\begin{tabular}{l}
   {\cellcolor{light-gray}\textbf{Background}}\\
   {\TextField[borderwidth=0,height=3cm,width=17.5cm,multiline=true]{}}\\
   \\
   \TextField[borderwidth=0,width=16.5cm]{Ideals}\\
   \TextField[borderwidth=0,width=16.5cm]{Flaws}\\
   \TextField[borderwidth=0,width=16.5cm]{Bonds} 
\end{tabular}
```

The first multiline box shows up correctly, but the remaining 3 boxes at the bottom don't. Has anyone encountered this and got it to work correctly?

Comment: Try enclosing the TextField in a `minipage` with definite dimensions to make sure that the spacing is right.